# Download file using jquery without redirecting

Tags: jquery, asp.net, file, download

I am trying to download a audio file using jquery as shown below and followed the best answers given but that didn't work out for me in my case.

1.[Download file using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)

2.[Using Jquery to download file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296085/download-file-using-jquery)

```
$("#downloadbtn").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();  //stop the browser from following
    var downloadUrl = "http://mysite:49223/" + $('#<%=downloadfilename.ClientID %>').val();
    setTimeout("window.location.assign('" + downloadUrl + "');", 1000);
});
```

And this is my button:

```
<button id="downloadbtn" class="btn btn-primary downloadbtn">Download</button>
```

Now the problem is instead of downloading the file its redirecting to the path.

Can anyone say me how do I do this?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20887794/3279419

Comment: I think thats the 2nd link given in my question

Comment: but it's a link to one of the answers

Answer (score 2):

Quite an old question, but I was looking to see if there were client side only options.  It seems that there is a download attribute as part of HTML 5, but support is fairly restricted at the moment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=download

The other alternative we use is a hidden iframe where you change the Content-Type and/or Content-Disposition headers to get the browser to trigger a download as per this answer: [Using jQuery and iFrame to Download a File](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16799531/276874)