# How to force download a file with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, download

I have a `jQuery ajax` form where a user submits his email, once the form has been submitted, the user should get an automated download of a file, the form looks like this:

```
$(".email-form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this),
    form_email = $form.find("input[name='email']").val(),
    url = $form.attr("action");

    var posting = $.post(url, { email: form_email });

    posting.done(function() {
        $(".popup-design").hide();
        $("input[name='email']").val("");
        $("#done").show();
    });
});
```

and also I need to have to user automatically download a file of my choice when `posting` is `done`. How can I do that?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes it was, removed it :)

Comment: @ChrisSpittles I know about the `download` attribute, but that won't do here cuz it has to happen automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to:

- Create an iframe and add it to your document.
- Set the iframe's SRC to be a URL to the download.
- Have the server send the correct headers to cause a download  prompt.

**Edit - Found this question which is very much related**

[Using jQuery and iFrame to Download a File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799483/using-jquery-and-iframe-to-download-a-file)