# Saving Iframe Content without "save button" colourbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, colorbox

I am working on a small project where I have a main html page; I have then made a separate settings.html file as well. I have the settings page popping up on click and displaying using:

```
jQuery('#settings').colorbox({iframe:true, width: "800px", height: "850px", onCleanup: function () { saveoptions(); } });
```

As you can see I have a custom function for on cleanup to save the settings. I don't want to have a save settings button on the settings page, just to have the user click out and then it prompts if you want to save. Problem is, I cant seem to access the iframe's elements when its closing down so I can save them.

How do you get access to the iframe's contents so that I can save them?

EDIT: If it helps, I am needing to access dropdown boxes and textbox values

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799483/using-jquery-and-iframe-to-download-a-file

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `contents()` method:

suppose you have iframe content: `<div id="myContent"></div>`

then use something like this:

```
$("#myiframe").contents().find("#myContent")
```

Also, the [second option here](http://roneiv.wordpress.com/2008/01/18/get-the-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript-crossbrowser-solution-for-both-ie-and-firefox/) may help you.