# Safari 10.0.1 $window.open in .then of a $http.get returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, safari

We have a problem when downloading a pdf document on a safari on MacOS Sierra. We get a dataUrl from a server and then use a $window.open with a createObjectURL to push the file to the browser. But all that doesn't actually matters. But here is a snippet to reproduce my problem:

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $window, $http) {       
    $scope.open = function() {
        var windowy = $window.open('', '_blank');
        console.log('1');
        console.log(windowy);
        $http.get('http://httpbin.org/delay/0').then(function(response) {
            var windowx = $window.open('', '_blank');
            console.log('2');
            console.log(windowx);
        });
    }
});
```

I created a JsFiddle to show the problem, the url is: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/9023/

Here is the log from chrome (mac)
[image: chrome console log]

And here is the log from safari 10 (mac)

[image: safari console log]

Why is the window undefined on safari in $http.get(...).then(...)

Comment: Pop up blocker.

Comment: why is the first window.open not blocked then ?

Comment: because you probably did a click action...

Comment: Safari still allows `window.open` in response to user actions when pop-ups are blocked. This is probably implemented as "allow if called in the context of a user action event handler".

Comment: check the jsfiddle, both window.open happen after each other in the click of a button, so the popup blocker should also block the 1st one

Comment: No the ajax call is asynchronous so it is not attached to the click event. The delay is what detaches it from the click event. Same thing would happen if you put it inside of a setTimeout.

Comment: Why use an Ajax call? Set the pop up with the url you are making an Ajax call to and set the proper headers to force a download.

Comment: in our solution the ajax calls fetches the file as a blob from the server stateless and authenticated using a session_token in the request headers

Comment: so you can do the same thing with the pop up....makes no difference they are both get requests... The server does not know the difference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799483/using-jquery-and-iframe-to-download-a-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we solved our problem in a pragmatic way, maybe not the most elegant solution, but for now it will do

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $window, $http) {       
    $scope.open = function() {
        var window = $window.open('', '_blank');
        $http.get('http://httpbin.org/delay/0').then(function(response) {
            console.log(window);
        }, function() {
            window.close();
     });
    } 
});
```