# Downloading files from expressJS (sendFile) server to VueJS, is returning corrupted files?

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, vuejs2, blob

I have an API written in expressjs, that sends a file when provided with a fileID.

The backend is working fine, as it sends the correct file (uncorrupted) when the route url is typed directly int the browser.
ex. http://localhost:8080/download?id=1234 (downloads all files just fine ie.txt, xlsx, jpg, zip)

My express route actually uses res.download, which is really jsut a wrapper for sendFile.

When I try calling these route urls from a Vue http get request, it only returns txt files uncorrupted. All other files download, but they can be opened, due to corruption.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction as to why its not working in Vue?

For clarity, "item" is passed as an argument to this function.

```
        this.$http.get("http://localhost:8000/files/download", {params:{id:item._id}}, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
      .then(response => {

        var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type:response.headers.get('content-type')});

        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = item.filename;
        link.click();
      })
```

For reference, this is my express route

Comment: try changing responseType to blob

Comment: Also `new Blob([response.data], { type: "text/plain" })`. See if this works

Comment: @Helpinghand Thank you for your suggestions! unfortunately, it still returns corrupted jpgs, zips, and xlsx files. Has to be something when its turned into a blob that messes it up.

Comment: I thought about just binding each files src attribute to  a "computed" string, since typing the routes directly in the browser downloads them correctly. But i feel this wont suffice once i implement authentication later on (and remove the cors open for all).

Comment: yea, won't be good once authentication is added.
I found this one, `type: 'application/pdf'`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50736657/vue-laravel-how-to-properly-download-a-pdf-file

Comment: I came across this issue but don't  remember what I did to get it done.

Comment: @Helpinghand I found the solution within the link you posted. The problme is that i was exlicitly sending params in its own object before asigning "content-type". The example you posted concatenates the query params to the url. After making this switch, its working perfectly.

Comment: Ohh so instead of passing params object you directly added `?id=1234` in your url and that worked?

Comment: @Helpinghand yes, exactly!

Comment: Oh thats Cool :D

Comment: I have no idea why this worked, but I found it to be the common denominator in all the examples people posted, where their code worked. Seems silly, but it works.

Answer (score 7):

Shout out to @Helpinghand for helping me troubleshoot this.

"I found the solution within the link you posted. The problem is that i was explicitly sending params in its own object before assigning "content-type". The example you posted concatenates the query params to the url. After making this switch, its working perfectly".

```
this.$http.get(`http://localhost:8000/files/download?id=${item._id}`, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.headers.get('content-type'));
        console.log(response);

        var blob = new Blob([response.body], {type:response.headers.get('content-type')});

        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = item.filename_version;
        link.click();
      })
```

Comment: I think [response.body] should be [response.data], at least that's what worked for me!

Comment: responseType arraybuffer is the key here. axios would require res.data