# Excel Export using laravel with vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5

I am Doting Excel export using Laravel with Vuejs, somehow the Code is returning true value but can not Download Excel file, if I do normal request it will download the file, but in axios request, it will not export the file

I am using php artisan make:export to export file

In App/Export/studentexport.php

```
public function collection()
{
    return Student_master::all();
}
```

then in controller i will do a function

```
public function export()
{
    return Excel::download(new StudentExport, 'users.xlsx');
}
```

In my Vue file i will write a code that cal call the controller and export the file

```
axios.get('api/export')
            .then(()=>{
                toast({
                    type: 'success',
                    title: 'Export the Data'
                })
            })
            .catch(()=> {
                toast({
                        type: 'warning',
                        title: 'Can not Export'
                        })
            })
```

but the result is like that
[image]

that will return True, I really don't know how to solve this,plase help me

Comment: Possibly this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50736657/vue-laravel-how-to-properly-download-a-pdf-file

Comment: I Can try this, but not working on this..any other way??

Answer (score 3):

I think is a little bit late but I had the same problem and I just solved it.

For download a file from vuejs, you shouldn't make the request as an Axios petition (at least not that I know). Instead, you can use a href and download attribute inside your template.

This is an example:

```
<a
    type="button"
    href="/api/export/entity/"
    download="file.xlsx"
>
    <button
        @click="export()"
        class="btn btn-primary"
    >
    Export
    </button>
</a>
```

The method helps if you need to do another stuff.

I hope this help you.

Comment: It's Works for me

Answer (score 2):

ok I solve the problem, I use Vue-excel-export package that will Export the Excel File

[enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-excel-export)

this link can help me to install package and use it