# Export CSV via Maatwebsite , Laravel

Tags: laravel, export-to-csv

I try to export a csv file with some data, but with my current code I get response 200, and some strange characters, and no download, not sure why.

Source URL  [here](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/import-and-export-csv-file-in-laravel-58example.html).

**Exports/DataExport.php**

```
namespace App\Exports;
use App\ViewData;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Excel;

class DataExport implements FromCollection
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        return ViewData::all();
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
use App\ViewData;
use App\Exports\DataExport;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
    .....
    //  Export CSV data
    public function export() 
    {
        return Excel::download(new DataExport, 'data.xlsx');
    }
```

I added in config/app.php file, service provider and aliase.

Comment: if you have `use Excel;` then change it to `use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;` inside your controller. If it works.

Comment: I edited the post for controller, with what I'm using now.

Comment: Your code is actually fine, I don't see any error. are you using 5.8 laravel version ?

Comment: The funny part is that I have no errors, just a random set of characters in response. PS. if helps I am using Postgres.

Comment: Try this from View instead of Collection. You might have a version issue. I haven't worked on Postgres, maybe it has some other procedure.

Comment: Not sure how to do that.

Comment: See maatwebsite for view data to export.

Comment: I tried some debugging. On dd() , I have data, if I try .csv in response I have data,  but the actual download actions still nothing.  I also tried FromQuery.  I will read the docs again, maybe I will find something.

Comment: Are you downloading the file from route directly or from a frontend framework, like vuejs or jquery ?

Comment: I am using VueJs on front.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is from front-end. I also find something similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56819483/excel-export-using-laravel-with-vuejs  , now I will look for a way to pass params, and the job is done. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are downloading the csv file from a frontend framework, so ofcourse it will gives you some strange characters instead of downloading a whole file, let me gives you a short code for that**

```
downloadCSV() {
let newWindow = window.open();
axios.get('/json/persons/export')
   .then(response => {
     newWindow.location = 'http://' + window.location.hostname + '/json/persons/export';
   });
}
```

You need to manually hit that url for the download to work. The rest you understand I think.