# Alternative to create file from blob without URL.createObjectURL()

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, axios, blob

I want to enable users to download their latest invoice as PDF when they click on a button.

My Rails API is sending PDF file data like so:

```
def invoice
  pdf_html = ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string(template: 'invoices/show')
  pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(pdf_html)
  send_data pdf, filename: 'file.pdf'
end
```

My React frontend requests it like so:

```
axios.request({
    url: "http://localhost:3001/invoice",
    responseType: 'blob'
  }).then(response => {
    console.log("invoice response:", response);
  }).then(blob => {
    const data = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    this.setState({ invoicePDFlink: data });
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log("invoice error:", error);
  });
```

This implementation is based on an answer I found here: [Using JS to consume a Rails send_data response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54823012/using-js-to-consume-a-rails-send-data-response)

If I run it, the API call throws the following error: `TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.`

I have since learned that `createObjectURL` is deprecated. I have found answers for workarounds using Mediastream but I haven't found any alternative for Blobs.

How can I solve this?

**EDIT**

I solved it myself. Solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it actually works as intended by changing the `axios` request to the following:

```
  axios.request({
    url: "http://localhost:3001/invoice",
    responseType: 'blob'
  }).then(response => {
    console.log("invoice response:", response);
    const data = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
    this.setState({ invoicePDFlink: data });
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log("invoice error:", error);
  });
```

And `URL.createObjectURL` is only deprecated when using it for media streams.
Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL